# SemanticMediawiki subobject with whitespace in name: #show stopped working

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

We had a Mediawiki instance with a long overdue update.

This notably included an update in the SemanticMediawiki extension.
After this update, our templates designed to show the contents of SMW subobjects do not display anything, when used on subobjects with a whitespace in the name.

Minimal example:

```
{{#subobject:name with whitespace
|text=Something to display
}}

{{#show:{{FULLPAGENAME}}#name with whitespace | ?text }}
```

This was correctly displaying `Something to display` before, but does not show it anymore.
Is it some new restriction in SMW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a bug in SMW 3.0.0, that is not present anymore after updating to 3.0.2